# MEL VS linear spectrograms for bioacoustics machine learning

Tags: clustering, feature-extraction, audio-recognition, spectral-clustering, umap

I don't have background in bioacoustics but working on a data-science project in bioacoustics.

I am working with animal vocalizations recorded at sampling rate of 250000.

Animals are bats, which are known to produce sounds in high frequency.

In background literature, I found the use of MEL spectrograms also for bats, and learnt that MEL spectrograms compress the range into log-scale.

But if so, I would expect infomation is lost for highest frequencies,
and if so, I would expect worse results in using MEL.

Now, for the sake of benchmarking, I would like to reduce the number of variables of my study, and if other works used MEL, well there shoudl be a reason.

First goal : I am trying to identify vocal units, i.e. discretize vocalizations that seems (at human perception) kind of continuous screeches.

- Can you help understand pros and cons of MEL VS linear spectrograms , when dealing with animal vocalizations?
- Can you mention some good practices to keep in mind, considering the above goal ?

Answer (score 1):

The most important is to  set the parameters of the mel spectrogram appropriately. This means both the temporal resolution, the frequency range and frequency resolution. For example, with `librosa.feature.melspectrogram` this would be configured using the parameters `n_fft`, `fmin`/`fmax` and `n_mels`. If you have existing papers that use mel spectrograms with success on a similar task, use the parameters they selected as a starting point.

Linear (STFT) spectrograms have many more bins on the frequency axis. This is usually unnecessary (for most tasks), and the higher dimensionality makes it harder for a model to learn patterns from.